# Can i use time A | B to measure the time taken to run A | B?

Tags: time

I imagine time A | B would only measure the time taken to run A (since the argument to time is A). What's the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the shell. e.g. [Bash has a keyword `time`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#index-time) that times the whole pipeline. An external implementation of `time` would only time `A` in your example. A workaround might be to explicitly run an extra shell:

```
time sh -c "A | B"
```

Comment: Technically `time` is not a builtin, but a keyword (in bash, and in ksh and zsh which have the same feature). It has to be so that `time` applies to the following compound command and not just to a simple command.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a subshell, e.g.

```
 time ( A | B )
```

at least when `time` is the bash builtin (but then a subshell is useless). If you want to use the [time(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html) command (see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/375893/50557)) you'll better explicitly run some `sh -c` like [answered by iikkachu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/377449/50557)