# Monitoring Java process memory utilization

Tags: linux

I have 24 GB RAM on my server(RHEL) and have assigned 2 GB Xmx value to a Java process.

I need to check if this 2 GB is being consumed completely. Can I check the top command and see if this Java process is consuming 8.3% memory(ie: 2/24) and make an assumption that its using 2 GB at that point. If its less than 8.3%, then I am assuming that it has not reached 2 GB mark. Let me know if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164653/actual-memory-usage-of-a-process

Answer (score 1):

Use `jvisualvm` (Included in JDK) and add a `JMX Connection.

The JMX connection based on the ip of your server and jmx port

In your `JVM settings`check which port is assigned to `jmx connection`, `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=xxxx`

If not check with `netstat -tulpn | grep java`