# How could we get the USS of a process

Tags: linux, process, memory

As far as I know there are several memory concepts: VSS RSS PSS and USS, in which USS(unique set size) is the physical memory exclusively used by a process(correct me if needed).

I think this should be a very useful value to let me know which process uses too many physical memory?

But how could we get this value? By ps or from any /proc file?
(I know a smem tool could help, but is there any built-in method?)

**Update 20231015**

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33381/getting-information-about-a-process-memory-usage-from-proc-pid-smaps/33388#answer-753506) mentions that /proc/<pid>/smaps_rollup has sum value:

```
grep "Private" /proc/1748/smaps_rollup 
Private_Clean:     55700 kB
Private_Dirty:     67628 kB
Private_Hugetlb:       0 kB
```

So we can get the whole value as:

```
awk '/Private/{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }' /proc/1748/smaps_rollup
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting information about a process' memory usage from /proc/pid/smaps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33381/getting-information-about-a-process-memory-usage-from-proc-pid-smaps)

Comment: @aviro Thanks for your response, but seems the post didn't provide answers directly. I need more time on this post and update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to [Getting information about a process' memory usage from /proc/pid/smaps](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33388/273579) includes the instruction to do so. It doesn't hand out the exact command for `USS` specifically, but it provides all the information and examples required to come up with the command that would work for `USS`.

> - `RSS` can be (approximately<sup>+</sup>) obtained by summing the `Rss:` entries in `smaps` (you don't need to add up the shared/private
>   shared/dirty entries).
>
>   ```
>     awk '/Rss:/{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }' /proc/$$/smaps
>   ```
>
> [...]
>
> - **`USS` isn't reported in `smaps`, but indeed, it is the sum of private mappings, so you can obtain it the same way too**

So if `USS` is the sum of private mappings, you do it the same as you sum the `RSS`, but instead of summing all the line with `Rss:`, you sum all of the private mappings instead (`/Private/` instead of `/Rss:/`):

```
awk '/Private/{ sum += $2 } END { print sum }' /proc/$$/smaps
```